# Valums ajax fileupload asp.net - getting the number of successful uploads

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I have successfully implemented the Valums script for uploading multiple files asynchronously.
But I have two questions:

First is; I need the number of uploaded files (not the ones that fail). But I don't know how to get that information, since I am new to jquery. Let say, if the number of successful uploads is larger than 1, then I want to enable a button.

Secondly, the error messages that I send from the server are not shown in the web page.
These are the messages I send to the client:

```
context.Response.Write("{error: There has been an error on the server side. Please try again. }");
```

or

```
context.Response.Write("{success:true}");
```

where the {success:true} message is recognized by the script (as expected), but the other does not. How can I display the error messages that are generated by the server?

I am using ASP.NET/C# on the server side.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe I should have searched SO more carefully!

Here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055637/142600